# Rails 3 Nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a 2 level nesting objects that i need help with

My routes look like this to normalise the url abit. instead of having a url that looks like this /projects/1/tasks/3/comments/3.

```
resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end

resources :tasks do
  resources :comments
end
```

Model has the 'has_many', belongs_to methods.

I can create comments under each task and display them under the tasks, but on the 'show' template of the comments i would like to display a link back to the tasks, which i get an error because the tasks controller is asking for a project_id?

How would this normally done when dealing with 2 level nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

```
resources :projects, :shallow => true do
  resources :tasks do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Which is basically what you're doing except you can't generate a `projects_task` member path(ie `projects/1/tasks/1`) anymore they'd all just be `task` member paths(ie '/tasks/1').
*Member paths include `show`, `update`, `delete`, `edit`*

But the `project_tasks` collection paths(ie `projects/1/tasks`) would still be available.
*Collection paths include `index`, `create`, `new`*

`comment` paths wouldn't change. *All `comment` paths would still include the `task/:task_id` prefix.*

Checkout the [`resources` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) for more info on that (also more info on `member` and `collection` also on that page.)

**But to actually solve your problem**

You need to look up the `project_id` when you link back to the `project_tasks` index. So you would need to do

```
<%= link_to "Project Tasks Index", project_tasks_path(@task.project) %>
```

That way the `Task#index` knows where the parent project is. This is the solution for both implementations.

Check out the [`UrlFor` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) for more info on that.

**If you want access to a `@project` variable in a `Comment` view**

Then you just need to look up the `project` in the controller instead of at a view level. So basically

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @comment = @task.comments.find([:id])

    @project = @task.project
  end
end
```

Comment: That's great, with your solution, does that mean i still need to re-arrange my resources like your example? would finding the project id in the controller and assigning 'project_tasks_path(@project, @task) also work?

Comment: You don't have to rearrange your code, it's just a suggestion. Yes, you could set a `@project` variable in your controller and do it that way, but since you're going to the `project_tasks` collection `index` route you would only need the `@project` variable. If you were going to the `project_**task**` member `show` route then you would need both `(@project, @task)` parameters.

Comment: sorry, i'm actually going to the task show, so the parent of comment. would that mean i need to do the later and how do i assign the project variable in my controller? would it be something like this @project = Project.find(params[:task.project]) ???

Comment: Then yeah you would need to do the latter, I'll update my answer to give you an example on how to get a `Task`'s parent `Project` object in a `Comment` view.

Comment: That worked the treat, i have another problem now, my cucumber test can't find the comments tasks. Given /^that task has a comment:$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    @task.comments.create!(attributes)
  end
end

Comment: You should probably make another question for that, that way you could post relevant code and errors in that question. So it would probably be a good question to with a different context since this one was mainly about `view` generation and routing.